# call a bash variable which has spaces

Tags: bash, svn

I have a test SVN script in bash that calls tags which has spaces in it. This is stored in a variable. See below,

```
#!/bin/bash


grepper="trunk-index FOR in footer"

a=`svn ls -v file:///var/tags/folderrepo | grep $\"grepper\" | awk '{print $1}'`
echo $a
echo $grepper
```

echo $a gives no such or directory for FOR in and footer
echo $grepper gives the content of the variable grepper

On the command line, I can call the tag using Quotes,

```
[user@test scripts]# svn ls -v file:///var/tags/folderrepo | grep "trunk-index FOR in footer"
131  ?                    Jul 29 16:21 trunk-index FOR in footer/
```

However, the same cannot be called even when I put quotes in the script. 
What needs to be put on the grep so that the tag which has spaces in it can be called from a bash script.

Thanks!

Comment: One doesn't "call" a variable. Only functions are called.

Answer (score 0):

grep isn't going to see that you're passing it a shell variable. Shells expand/replace their variables before firing up the requested program. so grep thinks it's being invoked as

```
... | grep trunk-index FOR in footer | ...
```

and end up searching for the phrase `trunk-index` in some non-existent files `FOR`,`in`, and `footer`.

Try

```
 ... | grep '$grepper' | ...
```

instead.

Comment: I tried this but it gives no output on doing a echo $a. How do I make sure grep understands the variable can contain spaces? Or we would have to ask the user not to put spaces which has to be done as a last resort.

Comment: that's not grep's job. it's your job to pass in an appropriate argument. grep only accepts ONE search term, so you have to make your arbitrary string be treated as a single argument. hence the `'` quotes in my answer.

Comment: That will pass the literal string `'$grepper'` to the `grep` command. If you want the content of the `$grepper` variable to be expanded, use double quotes: `... | grep "$grepper" | ...`. The double quotes in this case cause the shell to treat the value of `$grepper` as a single "word", even if it contains spaces.